# Unix Split Function to split file into multiple files : splitting the record

Tags: csv, unix, split

I have requirement to split the file into multiple file before FTP ( since FTP have limitation of 1 GB). I am using SPLIT function to do so.

```
split --bytes=$SPLIT_FILE_SIZE $FILE -d $FILE"_"

$SPLIT_FILE_SIZE=900M
```

Now i am noticing that it is splitting the record also.
Also my data in record does not have any NEW LINE character in it.

For e.g.

My original file have

```
a|b|c|d|e|f
a1|b1|c1|d1|e1|f1
a2|b2|c2|d2|e2|f2
a3|b3|c3|d3|e3|f3
a4|b4|c4|d4|e4|f4
```

So my split file is

First file content :

```
a|b|c|d|e|f

a1|b1|c1|d1|e1|f1

a2|b2|c2|
```

Second file Content :

```
d2|e2|f2

a3|b3|c3|d3|e3|f3

a4|b4|c4|d4|e4|f4
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can i avoid splitting up the records but split on end of lines.

Comment: @Prajakta, the best place to put your question is [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34440994/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking it to split by counting bytes, it doesn't care if the split point is the middle of the line. Instead, get the average of number of bytes per line, add some safety margin and split by line.

```
split -l=$SPLIT_FILE_LINE $FILE -d $FILE"_"
```

You can count the number of lines in the file using `wc -l $FILENAME`. Note that Mac OS X and FreeBSD distributions don't have the -d` option.

Comment: The `--line` option isn't available in FreeBSD or OSX. If you're using tools or options that are specific to just one platform, it's a good idea to mention which platform!

Comment: I might have to do "get the average of number of bytes per line" this would solve my problem hopefully. I am using Krone shell.

Answer (score 1):

This can be added to as you need, but in the most basic form, as long as you're dealing with text input, you may be able to use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
 inc=1
}

s > 900*1024*1024 {        # 900MB, per your question
 inc++
 s=0
}

{
 s+=length($0)
 print > "outfile." inc
}
```

This walks through the file, line by line, adding the length to a variable, then resetting the variable and incrementing a counter to be used as an output filename.

Upgrades might include, perhaps, taking the size from a command line option (`ARGV[]`), or including some sort of status/debugging output as the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it

SPLIT_FILE_SIZE=900

avg_length_of_line=`awk '{ total += length($0); count++ } END { print total/count }' $FILE`

r_avg_length_of_line=`printf "%.0f\n" "$avg_length_of_line"`

max_limit_of_file=`expr $SPLIT_FILE_SIZE \* 1024 \* 1024`

max_line_count=`echo $((max_limit_of_file / r_avg_length_of_line))`

split -l $max_line_count $FILE -d $FILE"_"